# Element 'handle': Character content other than white space is not allowed because the content type is 'element-only

Tags: magento2, xml, magento2.3.4

Migration from `Magento1` to `Magento2` was done using the data migration tool successfully.

However, certain product pages end up throwing the `exception` as seen on the attached screenshot.

To isolate the issue, I did even disable the custom module created for data migration. [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer posted by @CodeForGood is correct but incomplete.

I got this error in the category pages too.

No matter where you get it, the root of the issue is the same.

This happen because Data Migration Tool migrates the NULL values as string, instead of `NULL` itselfs.

For example, in the screenshot below there are 2 rows. Note the column `custom_layout_update_file`.

The first row was created by Data Migration Tool (INCORRECT). The second row is a new category created by me manually from the Magento 2 dashboard (CORRECT).

To fix this massively, run the following SQL query:

```
UPDATE INSERT_TABLE_NAME_HERE SET value = NULL WHERE attribute_id = INSERT_ATTRIBUTE_ID_HERE
```

In my case, the problem was being generated by the category attribute `custom_layout_update_file`. Its `attribute_id` is `530` and the column is located at `catalog_category_entity_text`. So, my final query was:

```
UPDATE catalog_category_entity_text SET value = NULL WHERE attribute_id = '530'
```

Then, reindex and clear cache:

```
bin/magento i:rei && bin/magento c:c && bin/magento c:f
```

Your product/category pages should be working properly now :)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

May be help you this...

This issue is XML file issue.

Your any custom module you missed White space.

This problem you got because the XML code, you copy directly on internet/webpage, there is some hidden character before start each line. This isn't space/ newline character. So, when push to Magento, Magento doesn't know this character, and it shows errors as your message. Solutions: clear all space between tag and order again.

And refer this link :-

[Magento 2 : How to solve the message "Character content other than whitespace"?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/177261/magento-2-how-to-solve-the-message-character-content-other-than-whitespace)

Comment: Hi Mohit, thanks, I have already tried this without any luck before posting here.

Comment: Turns out this was an issue with the custom module we had purchased, and was a result of an error in their di.xml file.

Comment: I don't have any custom module yet on the new migrated site. So, I'm not sure where it is originating from.

Comment: you created xml file in custom module or custom theme

Comment: you created today any xml files??

Comment: I had a custom module created for the data migration which I have now disabled to see whether any of XML files in it was causing the issue. Nothing else created to date. I am only testing the Magento 2 site with Luma theme and the data migrated from Magento 1 site.

Comment: you check your cerated custom module xml or theme xml

Comment: you disable the your custom module and check..

Comment: Yes, I did disable it long ago so I am now sure that the problem is with the core Magento XML file.

Comment: I did also remove the extra lines from default.xml file and default_head_blocks.xml.

Comment: You create the custom theme ??

Comment: No, we would use Magento Luma theme only, no custom theme.

Comment: so you purchased any extension ??

Comment: No. we didn't purchase any extension.

Comment: okay i will find this solutions

Comment: Thanks Mohit for your time and efforts. I have been trying to figure this out for nearly a week now.

Comment: Hi Mohit, finally fixed. I need to tell you that it has nothing do with any XML file, but had something around the attribute set. I will explain it in detail.

Comment: Hello please explain me briefly??

Comment: Hi Mohit. I am going to answer my own question hoping it would help save someone's time.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the product page displaying the error above got clear when the cause was found to be something around attribute set migrated from Magento 1.9.2.2. I had to move custom_layout_update_file from from unassigned attributes on the right to the right group on the left. I attached the screenshots for your reference.

Once this is done, one can now view an option 'Custom Layout Update' under Migration_Design tab that you see on editing a product from the admin.

The value to choose from the Custom Layout Update drop down for the product that displays XML errors is 'No Update' and save it. [image]